# How to make multi-dementional arrays with array lists wiht axios and vue js

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, multidimensional-array, axios

I am quite new to the axios and javascript and I am so confused with making multi-dimentional array.

#### 1. I want my data to look like :

[image]

```
userList: [
                    {
                        user_no: 1,
                        user_nickname: "hailey",
                    },
                    {
                        user_no: 2,
                        user_nickname: "mandi",
                    },
                    {
                        user_no: 3,
                        user_nickname: "loren",
                    },
                    {
                        user_no: 4,
                        user_nickname: "james",
                    },
],
```

#### 2. But from axios response, I am getting result like this :

[image]

```
{user_no : 1, user_nickname : "hailey"}
{user_no : 2 , user_nickname : "mandi"}
{user_no : 3 , user_nickname : "loren"}
{user_no : 4 , user_nickname : "james"}
```

How can I wrap those individual lists into multi dimentional array so I can make #2 -> #1 ?
I saw some functions like flat which does the opposite of what I want. So I was wondering if there's any way like those to wrap all arrays with outer array.

Comment: what you are getting in axios is an array with 5 objects just as you wanted. are you looking for something different

Comment: Am I???!! ughh, I am trying to use v-data-table but it is not showing with the results I got frorm the axios so I thought I need to wrap once more... I guess I am wrong with somewhere else then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not see any issues with the `axios` response you are getting. As `v-data-table` need an `array` to iterate and you are getting the same from the API response.

**Working Demo :**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    dataList: [{
            "user_no": 1,
            "user_nickname": "hailey"
    },
    {
      "user_no": 2,
      "user_nickname": "mandi"
    },
    {
      "user_no": 3,
      "user_nickname": "loren"
    },
    {
      "user_no": 4,
      "user_nickname": "james"
    }]
  }),
  computed: {
    gridHeaders() {
      return [
        { text: "User Number", value: "user_no" },
        { text: "User Nickname", value: "user_nickname" }
      ];
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.5.0/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app">
    <v-data-table :headers="gridHeaders" :items="dataList" item-key="user_no">
    </v-data-table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, it figures out that I needed to do response.data.data so it can go to deeper level! Thanks for help :D

Answer (score 0):

I was being stupid.
As the answer above said, there is nothing wrong with my data or code. But when I was getting data, the objects are actually insde the data so the structure was like this :

```js
response.data.data //i was calling it response.data ^^:;
```

Thank you for help :D

[image]